# Any relations between eigenvalues of $A$ and $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to solve a problem, and I think it comes down to using a relationship between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $M=1/2 (A+A^T)$. However, I don't know how to relate their eigenvalues. All I know about $A$ is that it is square and is positive definite (but not necessarily symmetric).

My goal is to show that

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \lambda_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2} \ge \lambda_\min(M) > 0$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, from largest to smallest (in absolute value).
Thanks.

**Edit**: After working through the problem again, I now see that the numerator
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \lambda_i$$ is always real, although each $\lambda_i$ is not necessarily real.

Comment: How can you be sure that the lhs is real?

Comment: Perhaps you're meant to take the real part of the left hand side.

Comment: Well I'm given that $v^T A v > 0$ for all $v$. So if $v_i$ is an eigenvector, then that tells us $\lambda_i > 0$. Is this implicitly telling us the eigenvalues are all real?

Comment: Nevermind, seems that it's only given for real $v$.

Comment: When you say "positive definite" I think you mean "has strictly positive eigenvalues". "Positive definite" in standard parlance implies symmetry, unless the relevant inner product is specified to not be the Euclidean one.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that positive definite also means symmetric. I think it caused me a lot of confusion. Now my understanding is that $v^T Av > 0$ just means that the real eigenvalues are positive,and only means that A is positive definite if $A$ is symmetric. Is that right?

Comment: $v^T A v$ having a definite sign implies symmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it suffices for your purposes to note that $\Re(\lambda_{min}(A)) \geq \lambda_{min}(M)$. To see that this is the case, proceed as follows:

Let $\lambda$ be an (complex) eigenvalue of $A$, and $x$ an associated (complex) eigenvector.  For convenience, let's specify that $\|x\| = 1$.  Note that
$$
\Re(\lambda) = \Re(\lambda x^*x) = \Re(x^*Ax) = x^*Mx \geq \lambda_{min}(M)
$$
For that middle equality, note that $x^*Mx = \frac 12 [(x^*Ax) + (x^*Ax)^*]$. Here, $*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose.

Comment: +1 This solves the op problem, but I guess the question need a new title now; or you also add the solution to the problem asked in the title

Comment: Ya, maybe the problem I'm trying to solve means the real part. I took it from an exam. That's the only way I see the question making any sense.

Comment: Thanks, after looking through the problem again, I now see that the numerator is always real (see edit).